# VS code, cant debug. error = path must be type string

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug my C project in vs code and the "makefile tools" debug option.
when I try to debug, after choosing the out file I get the following error:

- The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

I would appreciate any help, thanks a lot.

I've been searching all over for a sulution. reinstall the extention and fiddle much around with the settings.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "debug ... using a makefile".  makefiles are for building projects, not debugging them.  Are you trying to debug your program?  or are you trying to debug why your makefile is not properly building things?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, I assumed that the debugger need to accses the source files as I'm adding breakpoints and observing the steps on them. I think that vs code have trouble to debug my program (my .out file) because it doesnt recognise the source files. I can debug simple programs that i create without makefile in vscode.

Comment: Yes, for sure the debugger needs access to the source files.  But it doesn't use makefiles to find them.  The location of the source files is (typically) built into the debug information that the compiler generates when you compile the code.  You're going to need to be more specific about what you're doing and what the problem is.  Also, please don't link images in StackOverflow; instead cut and paste (with proper formatting as code blocks) the information needed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I realised that the problem was not connected to the extenstion and solved it by myself configuring the settings of the native debugger. 
Should I Delete the Question? Your comment did helped me but as you correctly wrote it's wasn't very clear.
Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

I hit a similar error message when using the NativeDebug extension with "gdb".  Ends up it wanted me to add a "cwd" (current working directory) to my launch.json. The missing 'path' was the 'cwd'.